# In the U.S., what is the simplest way to establish a payment plan for back taxes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I live in MD, U.S. My wife and I haven't filed taxes since 2014. We are sure we owe a large amount of money. We have money to throw at the problem, and would like it settled in the most painless way possible. We don't have any W-2s. My wife was a 1099 for a period. We don't have any paper work for that either. Is there a way we can just toss someone a chunk of change to work this out and set up a payment plan with the IRS for us so we don't have to deal with the headache?

Comment: No records of any kind? Or do you mean you lost the W-2s and such? You can contact the IRS and get copies of what they have had sent to them.

Comment: We are incredibly disorganized. Lost the W-2s and such. I am aware that I can contact the IRS to get copies of what was sent there, but I'd be happy to pay someone to do this for me if possible.

Comment: Best place to start is by creating an IRS.gov login and check online what status your taxes are in, so you know your starting point.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way we can just toss someone a chunk of change to work this out?

Yes. The someone you are looking for is an accountant (CPA). Your situation is complicated enough that you should interview more than one and get an estimate of what they think it will take to straighten everything out. You want an accountant that can not only fix the mess that you have put yourselves in, but also teach you how to properly run your business. (If you are getting 1099 income, then you are self-employed with your own business.)

You might also require the services of a tax attorney, because failure to file taxes can be considered a criminal act. Your accountant can advise you if he or she thinks you need an attorney.

Most importantly, don’t wait. Things get worse if the IRS contacts you before you contact them.

Comment: Might even be a good idea to go in the opposite order: find a tax attorney you're comfortable with, and use their suggested accountant to actually fill out the forms. This is the order my FIL did when his wife passed away and found out that his wife had not filed for nearly a decade.

Answer (score 1):

You can always file past returns. You won't get any refunds owed to you that are older than three years and you will have penalties and interests applied to amounts owed. You indicate that you don't have any records. This is bad, especially if you have a complicated tax situation (or have significant cash based income).

You need to start by requesting copies of past tax forms from employers, banks, etc. You can also get IRS to send you what information has already been provided to them. I doubt that any accountant will do this requesting for you.

Once you have all of that, you need to go and fill out the tax forms. You can probably pay someone to do this part. With no records, you will have difficulty trying to itemize or take advantage of deductions. Assuming you owe money, you either pay the total amount or send in a request for a payment plan form with the return. The IRS will then respond whether they accept or not. You could also try calling the IRS and asking for help, they might be willing to reduce penalties and interest.

Don't forget that Maryland will also be very interested in getting any owed state taxes as well. You'll have to get current with them as well.